# someUiTextField.delegate = self App crashes at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    someUiTextField.delegate = self // App crashes here     
}
```

I get the following exception:

> `NSInvalidArgumentException`,  terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

Comment: can you show the full error

Comment: Check your Outlet `someUiTextField` is connected with your controller.

Comment: Please post error log.So we can help you.

Comment: All required delegate functions implemented?

Comment: Thanks ! for all your help through comments. @NiravD thanks man as the problem was with the connection I guess. I just created a complete new project and the same code worked just fine... :)